# Overwriting text file in C

Tags: c, file, printf, overwrite, fclose

I would like to start off with this is my first post and I am not doing this as a homework assignment, but rather to just introduce myself to writing in C.

I'm trying to constantly overwrite the file with my for loop, however halfway through the numbers start to go crazy.

Here is the output:

y =  19530

y =  3906

y =  78119530

y =  15623906

y =  -1054493078

Can anyone please provide an explanation as to why in the 3rd iteration of the loop, it jumps to 78119530?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
int x = 19530;
int y;
FILE *buff;
buff = fopen("BUFF.txt","w+");

for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i++){
    fprintf(buff, "%d", x);
    rewind(buff);
    fscanf(buff, "%d", &y);
    printf("y =  %d\n", y);
    y = y/5;
    fclose(fopen("BUFF.txt", "w+"));
    fprintf(buff, "%d", y);

    }

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your program is broken in numerous ways. Why don't you do any error checking? Why do you always print `x` and then read `y`?

Comment: Nevermind I am an idiot lol. :(

Comment: So I removed     fprintf(buff, "%d", x); and  rewind(buff); out of the for loop, now my output to the user is correct. However, my output to the file is still incorrect.

Comment: Please show me the update code. I think you also need another `rewind()` between the `fscanf()` and the `fprintf()` as the `fscanf()` call modifies the file pointer as well.

Comment: My issue was resolved by making the above changes and using freopen as user Paddy stated below, thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 4):

You are leaking file streams.  The following line is incorrect:

```
fclose(fopen("BUFF.txt", "w+"));
```

What you are doing here is opening the file again, and closing the *new* stream, leaving the old stream (kept in `buff`) valid.

You want this:

```
fclose(buff);
buff = fopen("BUFF.txt", "w+");
```

Or this:

```
freopen("BUFF.txt", "w+", buff);
```

Comment: I see, thank you! I thought my statement would be equivalent to freopen.